# Why does this tree have a round hole?

Tags: trees

One of my soccer students was hiding behind a tree when he discovered this hole. I've tried Googling it but I couldn't find out why this tree has a hole.

[image]

Comment: It looks like somebody just pulled out the outer layer of bark. I don't think there's anything special about it.

Comment: I agree. There was some sort of cut or other injury to the outer layers of the tree (bark and some of the living tissue just underneath it), and when the bark grew back it was not in concert with the rest of the bark, and formed a different pattern.